# MySQL - generate numbers for groups of a result

Tags: mysql

I need a query to return this result:

```
+---------+-----+-------+
| ref_nid | nid | delta |
+---------+-----+-------+
|   AA    | 97  |  1    |
|   BB    | 97  |  2    |
|   CC    | 97  |  3    |
|   DD    | 98  |  1    |
|   EE    | 98  |  2    |
|   FF    | 98  |  3    |
+---------+-----+-------+
```

However, I do not have the delta column.  I need to generate it for each nid group.

In other words, I need an auto incremented number for each group of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [guy's blog](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/)

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* from player p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by score desc limit 10;
```

Basically,

```
set @i = 0; 
select id, @i:=@i+1 as myrow from mytable
```